# gulp-autoprefixer не работает (не устанавливает префикс)

Tags: gulp

У меня в проекте есть свойство `background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)), url('../img/mobile_app/2_img.jpg') center no-repeat` и **gulp-autoprefixer** для него не создаёт префикс. Других свойств где требуется префикс у меня нет. Во время установки пакета **gulp-autoprefixer** ошибки никакой не появлялось и после запуска `gulp` никаких ошибок тоже не было.  Открывал я свой сайт в chrome. В проекте используется SASS.

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const browserSync = require('browser-sync');
const sass = require('gulp-sass')(require('sass'));
const rename = require("gulp-rename");
const cleanCSS = require('gulp-clean-css');
const autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');


gulp.task('server', function() { 

    browserSync({ 
        server: {
            baseDir: "src" 
        },
        browser: 'google chrome',
        open: 'local'
    });
});

gulp.task('styles', function() {
    return gulp.src("src/sass/**/*.+(scss|sass)")
        .pipe(sass({outputStyle: 'compressed'}).on('error', sass.logError)) 
        .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min', prefix: ''}))
        .pipe(cleanCSS({compatibility: 'ie8'}))
        .pipe(autoprefixer({
            cascade: false
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest("src/css"))
        .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});

gulp.task('watch', function() { 
    gulp.watch("src/sass/**/*.+(scss|sass)", gulp.parallel('styles'))
    gulp.watch("src/*.html").on('change' browserSync.reload);
})

gulp.task('default', gulp.parallel('watch', 'server', 'styles'));
```